Ding Gorenstein dimension
It is known that Gorenstein projective and Gorenstein injective dimensions of a ring R are equal. Is true also for ding projective and ding injective dimensions ?

I suggest you include some background. I would be surprised if more than one reader of MathOverflow knew (without doing some research) what the Ding projective dimension is (and I’m pretty sure that “Ding” should have a capital “D”). But I wouldn’t be surprised if more than one could answer your question if you gave them a bit more help.
